# Netty Pipeline object parsing

Tags: java, netty

Currently I have a single handler at the end of my netty pipeline that does almost all the request logic. (Parsing a object from json using jackson, authentication, rate limiting, etc. Would it be a better use of the pipeline structure to put these at stages along the pipeline after the executer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's matter of re-usability etc. Often you have a handler for decoding, one for encoding and one for the business logic. This allows for better re-usability and also for easier testing.